# How many ways to add to 32?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have been presented with a rather complex combination problem.

**Using only the numbers 2, 4, 6 and 8, how many possible ways can you add up to 32 if the number 4 may only be used no more than once in any solution?**

Also including solutions that do not use the number 4, I can find 29 unique solutions when the order doesn't matter.

Solution 1:     8   8   8   8
Solution 2:     8   8   8   4   2   2
Solution 3:     8   8   8   2   2   2   2
Solution 4:     8   8   6   6   4
Solution 5:     8   8   6   6   2   2
Solution 6:     8   8   6   4   2   2   2
Solution 7:     8   8   6   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 8:     8   8   4   2   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 9:     8   8   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 10:    8   6   6   6   6
Solution 11:    8   6   6   6   4   2
Solution 12:    8   6   6   6   2   2   2
Solution 13:    8   6   6   4   2   2   2   2
Solution 14:    8   6   6   2   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 15:    8   6   4   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 16:    8   6   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 17:    8   4   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 18:    8   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 19:    6   6   6   6   6   2
Solution 20:    6   6   6   6   4   2   2
Solution 21:    6   6   6   6   2   2   2   2
Solution 22:    6   6   6   4   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 23:    6   6   6   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 24:    6   6   4   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 25:    6   6   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 26:    6   4   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 27:    6   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 28:    4   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Solution 29:    2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2

That in itself was rather challenging, but there are additional restrictions:

**A. Order DOES matter. That is to say, something like [8,8,6,6,4] is indeed considered a different solution than [8,8,6,4,6].**

**B. Any solution that does use the number 4, must BEGIN with the number 4.**

If I treat any elements that have the same value as other elements within a given solution as unique, I can take *n*! where *n* is the number of elements within each solution. Naturally, for those solutions that contain the number 4, I use (*n*-1)! instead. That provides me with a whopping 21,104,423,119,848 solutions.

Taking repeating elements as non unique, using n!/(n1! x n2! x n3! x ... x nk!) for all solutions that don't contain the number 4, and the same but using (n-1)! in the numerator for solutions that do contain the number 4, I find a greatly reduced 1,577 solutions.

Now here's the part I'm struggling with.

**C. There are two unique ways to include the value 2 in a solution.**

**D. There are four unique ways to include the value 8 in a solution.**

**E. There are five unique ways to include the value 6 in a solution.**

That is to say there are different "versions" of each value.

**F. No versions of 6 or 8 may be repeated within any single solution**

For clarity, assume we have [8,8]. There are 4 "versions" of 8 that may be used, but not repeated within a solution. [8a,8a] for instance is not valid. This could be [8a,8b] or [8a,8c] or [8a,8d] or [8b,8a] or [8b,8c] etc.

Assume you had [2,2]. Because you CAN repeat "versions" of 2, you could use [2a,2b] or [2b,2a] or [2a,2a] or [2b,2b].

There you have it.

Following all of the restrictions, how many different ways can you add up to 32?

Comment: If order matters then in general things are easier than if it does not, we are dealing with *compositions* and not *partitions*.

Comment: I also have no idea what you mean by (C),(D),(E) or (F). What are you trying to say here? What sums are not allowed under these circumstances?

Comment: A generating function call for you :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews   Apologies for the lack of clarity. Let me try a different way. The desired end sum is always 32.

Comment: That was practically the only thing about the question that I understood, @AndySmith

Comment: @ThomasAndrews   Let me try a different way. End sum is always 32.

Let us use colors. Green, Blue, Red, and Yellow have value 8. You can not repeat any of these within a solution.

Pink, Black, White, Purple and Orange have value 6. You can not repeat them within a solution.

Gold and Silver each had a value of 2, and you CAN repeat them.

So a possible solution could be [Blue, Green, Gold, Black, Silver, Gold, Gold, Gold]  that is 8+8+2+6+2+2+2+2=32.

[Green, Blue, Gold, Black, Silver, Gold, Gold, Gold] would be considered a different solution. Does this help clarify at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The count is $7424856$.

The natural approach, since order matters, is to use an exponential generating function (we'll use a variable $t$).  Since each symbol has a value, and we want the total value to be $32$, we use a second variable $x$ to keep track of value:
if a symbol has value $v$ and can be used at most $r$ times, we introduce a factor
$$\left(1+x^v t + x^{2v}\frac{t^2}{2!} + \cdots + x^{rv}\frac{t^r}{r!}\right)$$
corresponding to that symbol.  (If $r=\infty$ this factor is $\exp(x^v t)$.)

Let $f(x,t)$ be the product of these factors over all symbols.  (In your problem there will be multiple factors for a given value $v$, since we have multiple symbols with the same value.)  Given a sum $s$, and a length $l$, the number of strings of length $l$ and total value $s$ is the coefficient of $x^s t^l/l!$ in $f(x,t)$.

For your example, we'll ignore the $4$ for now, as you suggest.  We have
$$f(x,t)=e^{2 t x^2} \left(1+t x^6\right)^5 \left(1+t x^8\right)^4;$$
we get our answer by computing the coefficient of $x^{32}$ (which is a polynomial in $t$), and the coefficient of $x^{28}$ (to account for strings with a $4$ in front), adding these two together, and replacing $t^k$ by $k!$.

We find $[x^{28}]f(x,t)$ and $[x^{32}]f(x,t)$ are
$$=\frac{8 t^{14}}{42567525}+\frac{8 t^{12}}{31185}+\frac{16 t^{11}}{14175}+\frac{4
   t^{10}}{63}+\frac{32 t^9}{63}+\frac{16 t^8}{5}+\frac{80 t^7}{3}+50 t^6+88
   t^5+60 t^4$$
and
$$\frac{2 t^{16}}{638512875}+\frac{8 t^{14}}{1216215}+\frac{16
   t^{13}}{467775}+\frac{8 t^{12}}{2835}+\frac{16 t^{11}}{567}+\frac{92
   t^{10}}{315}+\frac{32 t^9}{9}+\frac{34 t^8}{3}+56 t^7+122 t^6+60 t^5+t^4$$
respectively.  Adding these together, and substituting $k!$ for $t^k$ gives the answer $7424856$.

*Remark.* Instead of ignoring the $4$, we can incorporate it into $f(x,t)$ with the factor $(1+x^4)$; the power of $t$ no longer measures the length of the string, but just the length of the *permutable* part of the string (where order matters).  The result is the same.

*Example.* It's instructive to verify the calculation by looking at a smaller case, replacing $32$ by $8$ (and let's say there are no $4$'s.)  We have
$$[x^8]f(x,t)=\frac{2 t^4}{3}+10 t^2+4 t,$$
so the argument above implies there should be $4$ strings of length $1$, $10(2!)=20$ of length $2$, and $2/3(4!)=16$ of length $4$.  These are correct: the $4$ strings of length $1$ are the $4$ "versions" of the $8$ symbol; the $20$ strings of length $2$ are permutations of a $6$ and a $2$, in various versions, and the $16$ strings of length $4$ look like $2222$, where there are $2$ possible versions of each $2$.

Comment: I read the condition that there could be multiple fours, but the first had to be a four. Where is it implied the first four must be the only four?

Comment: The OP states it in bold in the second sentence of the problem.  (True, that condition doesn't seem to be included in constraints A-F.)

Comment: Ah, yes, there was so much space between the beginning and the conditions (A)-(F) that I misremembered the top of the question. @Tad